# SQLJDBC driver is not supported by JRE 1.7

Tags: java, jdbc, mssql-jdbc, sqljdbc

I am trying to develop RESTful JAVA web service using Netbeans and MS SQL Server 2008 as DBMS.

I am registering **sqljdbc4.jar** as a driver but still it is showing me this error while deploying the project. I tried all the options available online and also removed driver, relocated driver did every thing except uninstalling entire developing package(Netbeans, JDK, SQL Server 2008).

Following is the error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [webapptest1] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
>   Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: Do you also have the sqljdbc.jar on the classpath?

Comment: @joshiparas have you used sqljdbc4.1jar ? afaik, sqljdbc4.jar only support jre 1.5 and 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Use [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) which is an opensource driver which supports MS Sql Server